# how much time it takes for confirmation of iphone application from apple ? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

How much time it takes for confirmation of  iphone application from apple ? 
I have submitted an iphone application on last week (8th sept-2010), but still application is not reviewed by apple.
 How much time apple takes to approve iphone application ? (approximate).
Is it possible to know how many applications are currently in a queue (waiting for review) ? 
And out of those applications, where my application is ???

Comment: Is it true that the more time app takes to review, maximize the chances of rejecting an application ??

Comment: See also: [How long does it take to get an app approved for the AppStore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189952/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-an-app-approved-for-the-appstore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is a good question for steve@apple.com, or sjobs@apple.com...

If I'm not wrong, the process is a little bit complicated, some apps can have a really quick review and enter in the store in a few days, others can took a lot of time like some weeks and, if you are an exception, months.

I only know that the process is strictly related to the category of the App. If your app do something that is already did by another app in the store, the process will be a little bit longer than a new and original app. The other standards used to select which app has to be reviewed before another one, are still unknown.

Unfortunately, this information, is non official and probably Apple will never confirm that. I got this information during a meeting in Switzerland by a guy who has met some guys of the Apple review team and like every info provided "at second hand", it needs to take precautions before considering as truth.

Answer (score 1):

It took me 8 days. You're not going to find much information on the topic. It's all behind closed doors.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no, nein and non.

Applications have taken anything from a few hours to a few months to go through the review process.

There is no indication (other than what is shown in iTunes Connect) as to which part of the process your app is in.

There is no indication of how many apps are in the review queue.

There is no indication of where your app is in the queue.

Each app is different and will take a different amount of time to review.

It'll be done when it's approved. Or rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally seen review times vary from under 2 days to well over 1 month.  There's a page where it reports that 80% to 90% of submissions are reviewed within 1 week, but there's no way to know if your app is an exception, or in a fast queue or a slow queue.  Just wait and start working on your next app in the meantime.